# How to replace fully qualified path with the folder which has all files in R

Tags: replace, path, directory

example: I have path: "C:/Users/home/Documents/Coursera/R Programming/Week 2/rprog-data-specdata/specdata" which I use as parameter to the function I created. How can I replace a function call to pass as parameter specdata instead of full path?

Answer (score 0):

Find the last occurence of '/' and pass a pointer to that point to the function that you want to get specdata.

Tell me if you are having trouble implementing this, should be pretty simple.